# Regular Expression/Logic: 6 digit number which should not contain consecutive or continuously repeated digits

Tags: java, regex

I want a regular expression / code to check that it should be 6 digits, minimum and maximum is 6. It should not contain consecutive digits like **123456**, **654321**, 453212 etc.
That means no two digit can even be consecutive.
Also, It should not contains continuously repeated digits like 2**44**674.

Suggest some solution.

Comment: I think this is more than regex is capable of doing; you're probably going to have to use some procedural code to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a regex is certainly possible, but how sure are you I didn't make a typo somewhere?

```
^            # Start of string
(?:          # Start of non-capturing group:
 0(?![901])| # Match 0, unless followed by 9, 0, or 1
 1(?![0-2])| # etc...
 2(?![1-3])|
 3(?![2-4])|
 4(?![3-5])|
 5(?![4-6])|
 6(?![5-7])|
 7(?![6-8])|
 8(?![7-9])|
 9(?![890])
){6}         # 6 times
$            # End of string
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aO7bL2/1).

Comment: Typo in what sense? I didn't get you. Basically a user should not enter consecutive or continuous digits. If a person type or if its a type then it should throw a error.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant that when a regex gets as verbose as this one, it's easy to miss errors. I'm pretty sure that I didn't make any, though :)

Comment: It is a good start but its not working perfectly.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? You do know that you have to compile the regex using the `(?x)` modifier because it's a verbose regex?

Comment: It is accepting 135790 as containing consecutive as 1 is in the starting and  0 is in the end.

Comment: Also can u complain it. Sorry for this nut a little bit explanation will help. And if I open the link and add some more test string it is not testing those. Do I have to so something more to test those. I am new to this.

Comment: And the continuously same digits like 224555 regular expression i need to write separately or test it with a procedural code.

Comment: No, it is rejecting 135790 because 9 and 0 are consecutive. The regex is already documented; the only advanced feature I'm using there is a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and if you don't understand how regex101 works, you should look at their documentation.

Comment: And 224555 is rejected as well.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the support,

Comment: Help with this regex also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732926/regular-expression-logic-6-digit-number-which-should-not-contain-more-than-3-co?noredirect=1#comment55234627_33732926

Comment: I think you should be able to figure this out if you understood this answer (and see why it's an even worse idea to do this in regex).